# Google chrome throws 'Aw snap' after file upload on selenium ide

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE on a mac machine and I am getting 'Aw snap' error on Google Chrome as soon as I upload a file.

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you post your code, along with the HTML?

Comment: @Jonah So, I've been using the Selenium IDE and not selenium code, as mentioned. I have tried to do the same task using Selenium code and it worked, my challenge is doing the same in IDE.

So, there's no code which I could post here.